# Next.js Dockerfile build failed

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, docker-image, next.js13

I,m tyring to dockerize my next.js Application. But couldn,t build it.

**my Dockerfile**
`

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/

WORKDIR /usr/app/

COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

`

*when I,m trying to build i got these error:
*
`

```
#10 31.08 > **Build error occurred**
#10 31.08 **Error: Failed to collect page data for /blog/[id]**
#10 31.08     at /usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:743:15
#10 31.08     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
#10 31.08   type: 'Error'
#10 31.08 }
#10 31.19 **error Command failed with exit code 1.**
#10 31.19 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn build]: exit code: 1
```

`

I'm trying to build Next.js docker image.

Comment: Where is the data for your blog stored?